# Build Visual Studio Code With 8GB RAM Fails Regarding Heap

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, gulp

The short question is, can the build process be forced to run sequentially/serially rather than parallel?
I know when I've encountered builds that ran in parallel, causing memory issues, I'd be able to do something like `-j 1` (depending on the build type), to just use one core, and spare me memory issues.

The last time I built vscode was a few months ago.
I've done the standard:

```
$ yarn
$ yarn gulp vscode-linux-x64
```

In order for that to even succeed, I'd have to close out every application on my system because of the memory pressure.
I'd even change `--max_old_space_size` from 8192 to 4096 in `package.json`.
But now that isn't even enough. I'll get the error `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

From `./build/gulpfile.vscode.js`, I can see it calls `compile-build` from `./build/gulpfile.compile.js`.
So I thought I'd just run `$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 gulp compile-build`, but that didn't work.
I saw there was a `--series` argument for `gulp, so I tried` $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --series vscode-linux-x64`, but surprisingly, all cores were still being used and I'd run out of memory.

So far, I've narrowed it down to the `compilation.compileTask('src', 'out-build', true)` step in `./build/gulpfile.compile.js`.
When I change `true` to `false`, I am able to get further. Although all cores are still being used, my RAM doesn't get choked out.

But even that isn't enough, because `optimizeVSCodeTask` in `vscodeTask` `./build/gulpfile.vscode.js` will fail because of some longfilename error.

So then I comment out that step, but then `vscodeTaskCI` will fail because it's expecting files from the optimize step in `out-vscode`. When I changed `sourceFolderName` to `out-build` instead, the vscode dir was created.

But when I ran `../VSCode-linux-x64/code-oss`, it opened up blank.
But when I add `VSCODE_DEV=0` to the command at the bottom of `../VSCode-linux-x64/bin/code-oss`, it runs.

It shouldn't have to be this way.
I know I could "solve" this issue by getting more RAM, but I think it could also be solved if I could somehow figure out a way to keep `node/yarn` to a single thread.

EDIT0: I tried setting the cpu affinity, and got it to use a single thread, but the RAM usage still climbed unreasonably.

EDIT1: Just for shiggles, I went ahead with the `swap` suggestion.
Since I start out with a base usage of 1.5GB, I set the swap to 2GB.
That wasn't enough. So I set it to 3GB. That too wasn't enough, my system would still hang, and I'd have to force a kernel oom check/call.

Finally, I set it to 4GB. That was just enough, but barely. It did end up hanging for maybe 5 seconds (right before I was about to kill it), before releasing and continuing on.

It got to 6.8/7.2GB RAM used, and 3.6/4GB of swap according to `htop`, as I sweated while watching it.

Swap would peak at one point, then drop back to ~1.5GB (my baseline RAM usage?), before climbing back up.

So what I can surmise from the excess usage, is that the build process IS using more RAM than it needs to (in that it's being swapped out).

I don't have memory issues like this with other build systems, and I've experienced this with other node projects.

I think even dotnet's webapps that use node, also end up using a good deal of memory when building.

So it'd still be nice to find a way to constrain node's memory usage.

Comment: Could you add swap file and increase your memory? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21988/giprn.html

Comment: I'm aware of swap, and have stopped using it years ago.
(odd, pressing enter here automatically submits)
When basically everything is closed, I'm left with 1.2GB used.
I couldn't imagine swapping out to a mechanical drive and the data getting paged back and forth.

Comment: But it would be simple solution. Few command, ok, compilation time would quadruple, but you don't have to dig into sources. Up to you...

Comment: But I've found in the past it isn't a solution for true memory hogging.
It's fine for small memory pressures, but this kind of build will take everything I've got.
When I've closed all programs I've previously opened, and nothing is left running but system stuff, then it's going to get really bad when there's that type of stuff getting swapped out.